# How should I create the model classes behind a video for my app?

Tags: android, json, rest, video, pojo

I'm creating a pretty straight-forward app (for right now) to play videos from the website Giantbomb.com. They have a public API, so I am using that. I'm building the app in MVP using Retrofit, OkHttp, RxJava, and Dagger2. That might be a bit overkill for the simplicity of my app, but I want to learn these libraries and architecture.

Right now it's a single activity app that I want to contain a scrollable list of tiles/cards of the top videos from the site. In each card I'm thinking of including a thumbnail image and video title. When you click the tile/card it plays the video. I'm thinking it would pull up a new activity (or fragment?) that will hold the video and description underneath, with the option to full-screen from there.

So, with all that out of the way. Right now I'm using `http://www.giantbomb.com/api/videos/?api_key=[my_api_key]&format=json`  as my initial api call. It returns the following (with many more "results", I cut it down to 2).

```
{
"error": "OK",
"limit": 100,
"offset": 0,
"number_of_page_results": 100,
"number_of_total_results": 11376,
"status_code": 1,
"results": [{
        "api_detail_url": "http:\/\/www.giantbomb.com\/api\/video\/2300-11935\/",
        "deck": "Rorie fights killer robots, Brad jams discs, Jeff breaks the law, and Jason can't put his phone away.",
        "hd_url": "https:\/\/giantbomb-pdl.akamaized.net\/2017\/03\/18\/mc_upf_031717_4000.mp4",
        "high_url": "https:\/\/giantbomb-pdl.akamaized.net\/2017\/03\/18\/mc_upf_031717_3200.mp4",
        "low_url": "https:\/\/giantbomb-pdl.akamaized.net\/2017\/03\/18\/mc_upf_031717_1800.mp4",
        "embed_player": "http:\/\/www.giantbomb.com\/videos\/embed\/11935\/",
        "id": 11935,
        "length_seconds": 7921,
        "name": "Unprofessional Fridays: 03\/17\/2017",
        "publish_date": "2017-03-17 17:33:00",
        "site_detail_url": "http:\/\/www.giantbomb.com\/videos\/unprofessional-fridays-03172017\/2300-11935\/",
        "url": "mc_upf_031717.mp4",
        "image": {
            "icon_url": "http:\/\/www.giantbomb.com\/api\/image\/square_avatar\/2926581-upf031717.jpg",
            "medium_url": "http:\/\/www.giantbomb.com\/api\/image\/scale_medium\/2926581-upf031717.jpg",
            "screen_url": "http:\/\/www.giantbomb.com\/api\/image\/screen_medium\/2926581-upf031717.jpg",
            "small_url": "http:\/\/www.giantbomb.com\/api\/image\/scale_small\/2926581-upf031717.jpg",
            "super_url": "http:\/\/www.giantbomb.com\/api\/image\/scale_large\/2926581-upf031717.jpg",
            "thumb_url": "http:\/\/www.giantbomb.com\/api\/image\/scale_avatar\/2926581-upf031717.jpg",
            "tiny_url": "http:\/\/www.giantbomb.com\/api\/image\/square_mini\/2926581-upf031717.jpg"
        },
        "user": "unastrike",
        "video_type": "Premium",
        "video_show": null,
        "video_categories": [{
                "api_detail_url": "http:\/\/www.giantbomb.com\/api\/video_category\/2320-10\/",
                "id": 10,
                "name": "Premium",
                "site_detail_url": "http:\/\/www.giantbomb.com\/videos\/premium\/"
            }
        ],
        "youtube_id": null
    }, {
        "api_detail_url": "http:\/\/www.giantbomb.com\/api\/video\/2300-11933\/",
        "deck": "Will this be the end of our robot nightmare or will we succumb to the onslaught of the dreaded boss rush?",
        "hd_url": "https:\/\/giantbomb-pdl.akamaized.net\/2017\/03\/17\/mc_bluebombin_03172017_4000.mp4",
        "high_url": "https:\/\/giantbomb-pdl.akamaized.net\/2017\/03\/17\/mc_bluebombin_03172017_3200.mp4",
        "low_url": "https:\/\/giantbomb-pdl.akamaized.net\/2017\/03\/17\/mc_bluebombin_03172017_1800.mp4",
        "embed_player": "http:\/\/www.giantbomb.com\/videos\/embed\/11933\/",
        "id": 11933,
        "length_seconds": 5700,
        "name": "Blue Bombin': Mega Man 4 - Part 04",
        "publish_date": "2017-03-17 16:18:00",
        "site_detail_url": "http:\/\/www.giantbomb.com\/videos\/blue-bombin-mega-man-4-part-04\/2300-11933\/",
        "url": "mc_bluebombin_03172017.mp4",
        "image": {
            "icon_url": "http:\/\/www.giantbomb.com\/api\/image\/square_avatar\/2926565-cp_megaman_04_part04.00_24_27_54.still001.jpg",
            "medium_url": "http:\/\/www.giantbomb.com\/api\/image\/scale_medium\/2926565-cp_megaman_04_part04.00_24_27_54.still001.jpg",
            "screen_url": "http:\/\/www.giantbomb.com\/api\/image\/screen_medium\/2926565-cp_megaman_04_part04.00_24_27_54.still001.jpg",
            "small_url": "http:\/\/www.giantbomb.com\/api\/image\/scale_small\/2926565-cp_megaman_04_part04.00_24_27_54.still001.jpg",
            "super_url": "http:\/\/www.giantbomb.com\/api\/image\/scale_large\/2926565-cp_megaman_04_part04.00_24_27_54.still001.jpg",
            "thumb_url": "http:\/\/www.giantbomb.com\/api\/image\/scale_avatar\/2926565-cp_megaman_04_part04.00_24_27_54.still001.jpg",
            "tiny_url": "http:\/\/www.giantbomb.com\/api\/image\/square_mini\/2926565-cp_megaman_04_part04.00_24_27_54.still001.jpg"
        },
        "user": "vinny",
        "video_type": "Premium",
        "video_show": {
            "api_detail_url": "http:\/\/www.giantbomb.com\/api\/video_show\/2340-9\/",
            "id": 9,
            "title": "Blue Bombin'",
            "position": 0,
            "site_detail_url": "http:\/\/www.giantbomb.com\/shows\/blue-bombin\/"
        },
        "video_categories": [{
                "api_detail_url": "http:\/\/www.giantbomb.com\/api\/video_category\/2320-10\/",
                "id": 10,
                "name": "Premium",
                "site_detail_url": "http:\/\/www.giantbomb.com\/videos\/premium\/"
            }
        ],
        "youtube_id": null
    }
],
"version": "1.0"
}
```

And when I use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to create the classes to represent this I get:

```
    -----------------------------------com.app.int_a.giantbombforandroid.Image.java-----------------------------------

package com.app.int_a.giantbombforandroid;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Image {

@SerializedName("icon_url")
@Expose
private String iconUrl;
@SerializedName("medium_url")
@Expose
private String mediumUrl;
@SerializedName("screen_url")
@Expose
private String screenUrl;
@SerializedName("small_url")
@Expose
private String smallUrl;
@SerializedName("super_url")
@Expose
private String superUrl;
@SerializedName("thumb_url")
@Expose
private String thumbUrl;
@SerializedName("tiny_url")
@Expose
private String tinyUrl;

public String getIconUrl() {
return iconUrl;
}

public void setIconUrl(String iconUrl) {
this.iconUrl = iconUrl;
}

public String getMediumUrl() {
return mediumUrl;
}

public void setMediumUrl(String mediumUrl) {
this.mediumUrl = mediumUrl;
}

public String getScreenUrl() {
return screenUrl;
}

public void setScreenUrl(String screenUrl) {
this.screenUrl = screenUrl;
}

public String getSmallUrl() {
return smallUrl;
}

public void setSmallUrl(String smallUrl) {
this.smallUrl = smallUrl;
}

public String getSuperUrl() {
return superUrl;
}

public void setSuperUrl(String superUrl) {
this.superUrl = superUrl;
}

public String getThumbUrl() {
return thumbUrl;
}

public void setThumbUrl(String thumbUrl) {
this.thumbUrl = thumbUrl;
}

public String getTinyUrl() {
return tinyUrl;
}

public void setTinyUrl(String tinyUrl) {
this.tinyUrl = tinyUrl;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.app.int_a.giantbombforandroid.Result.java-----------------------------------

package com.app.int_a.giantbombforandroid;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Result {

@SerializedName("api_detail_url")
@Expose
private String apiDetailUrl;
@SerializedName("deck")
@Expose
private String deck;
@SerializedName("hd_url")
@Expose
private String hdUrl;
@SerializedName("high_url")
@Expose
private String highUrl;
@SerializedName("low_url")
@Expose
private String lowUrl;
@SerializedName("embed_player")
@Expose
private String embedPlayer;
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("length_seconds")
@Expose
private Integer lengthSeconds;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("publish_date")
@Expose
private String publishDate;
@SerializedName("site_detail_url")
@Expose
private String siteDetailUrl;
@SerializedName("url")
@Expose
private String url;
@SerializedName("image")
@Expose
private Image image;
@SerializedName("user")
@Expose
private String user;
@SerializedName("video_type")
@Expose
private String videoType;
@SerializedName("video_show")
@Expose
private VideoShow videoShow;
@SerializedName("video_categories")
@Expose
private List<VideoCategory> videoCategories = null;
@SerializedName("youtube_id")
@Expose
private Object youtubeId;

public String getApiDetailUrl() {
return apiDetailUrl;
}

public void setApiDetailUrl(String apiDetailUrl) {
this.apiDetailUrl = apiDetailUrl;
}

public String getDeck() {
return deck;
}

public void setDeck(String deck) {
this.deck = deck;
}

public String getHdUrl() {
return hdUrl;
}

public void setHdUrl(String hdUrl) {
this.hdUrl = hdUrl;
}

public String getHighUrl() {
return highUrl;
}

public void setHighUrl(String highUrl) {
this.highUrl = highUrl;
}

public String getLowUrl() {
return lowUrl;
}

public void setLowUrl(String lowUrl) {
this.lowUrl = lowUrl;
}

public String getEmbedPlayer() {
return embedPlayer;
}

public void setEmbedPlayer(String embedPlayer) {
this.embedPlayer = embedPlayer;
}

public Integer getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
this.id = id;
}

public Integer getLengthSeconds() {
return lengthSeconds;
}

public void setLengthSeconds(Integer lengthSeconds) {
this.lengthSeconds = lengthSeconds;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public String getPublishDate() {
return publishDate;
}

public void setPublishDate(String publishDate) {
this.publishDate = publishDate;
}

public String getSiteDetailUrl() {
return siteDetailUrl;
}

public void setSiteDetailUrl(String siteDetailUrl) {
this.siteDetailUrl = siteDetailUrl;
}

public String getUrl() {
return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
this.url = url;
}

public Image getImage() {
return image;
}

public void setImage(Image image) {
this.image = image;
}

public String getUser() {
return user;
}

public void setUser(String user) {
this.user = user;
}

public String getVideoType() {
return videoType;
}

public void setVideoType(String videoType) {
this.videoType = videoType;
}

public VideoShow getVideoShow() {
return videoShow;
}

public void setVideoShow(VideoShow videoShow) {
this.videoShow = videoShow;
}

public List<VideoCategory> getVideoCategories() {
return videoCategories;
}

public void setVideoCategories(List<VideoCategory> videoCategories) {
this.videoCategories = videoCategories;
}

public Object getYoutubeId() {
return youtubeId;
}

public void setYoutubeId(Object youtubeId) {
this.youtubeId = youtubeId;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.app.int_a.giantbombforandroid.Video.java-----------------------------------

package com.app.int_a.giantbombforandroid;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Video {

@SerializedName("error")
@Expose
private String error;
@SerializedName("limit")
@Expose
private Integer limit;
@SerializedName("offset")
@Expose
private Integer offset;
@SerializedName("number_of_page_results")
@Expose
private Integer numberOfPageResults;
@SerializedName("number_of_total_results")
@Expose
private Integer numberOfTotalResults;
@SerializedName("status_code")
@Expose
private Integer statusCode;
@SerializedName("results")
@Expose
private List<Result> results = null;
@SerializedName("version")
@Expose
private String version;

public String getError() {
return error;
}

public void setError(String error) {
this.error = error;
}

public Integer getLimit() {
return limit;
}

public void setLimit(Integer limit) {
this.limit = limit;
}

public Integer getOffset() {
return offset;
}

public void setOffset(Integer offset) {
this.offset = offset;
}

public Integer getNumberOfPageResults() {
return numberOfPageResults;
}

public void setNumberOfPageResults(Integer numberOfPageResults) {
this.numberOfPageResults = numberOfPageResults;
}

public Integer getNumberOfTotalResults() {
return numberOfTotalResults;
}

public void setNumberOfTotalResults(Integer numberOfTotalResults) {
this.numberOfTotalResults = numberOfTotalResults;
}

public Integer getStatusCode() {
return statusCode;
}

public void setStatusCode(Integer statusCode) {
this.statusCode = statusCode;
}

public List<Result> getResults() {
return results;
}

public void setResults(List<Result> results) {
this.results = results;
}

public String getVersion() {
return version;
}

public void setVersion(String version) {
this.version = version;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.app.int_a.giantbombforandroid.VideoCategory.java-----------------------------------

package com.app.int_a.giantbombforandroid;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class VideoCategory {

@SerializedName("api_detail_url")
@Expose
private String apiDetailUrl;
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("site_detail_url")
@Expose
private String siteDetailUrl;

public String getApiDetailUrl() {
return apiDetailUrl;
}

public void setApiDetailUrl(String apiDetailUrl) {
this.apiDetailUrl = apiDetailUrl;
}

public Integer getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public String getSiteDetailUrl() {
return siteDetailUrl;
}

public void setSiteDetailUrl(String siteDetailUrl) {
this.siteDetailUrl = siteDetailUrl;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.app.int_a.giantbombforandroid.VideoShow.java-----------------------------------

package com.app.int_a.giantbombforandroid;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class VideoShow {

@SerializedName("api_detail_url")
@Expose
private String apiDetailUrl;
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("title")
@Expose
private String title;
@SerializedName("position")
@Expose
private Integer position;
@SerializedName("site_detail_url")
@Expose
private String siteDetailUrl;

public String getApiDetailUrl() {
return apiDetailUrl;
}

public void setApiDetailUrl(String apiDetailUrl) {
this.apiDetailUrl = apiDetailUrl;
}

public Integer getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
this.title = title;
}

public Integer getPosition() {
return position;
}

public void setPosition(Integer position) {
this.position = position;
}

public String getSiteDetailUrl() {
return siteDetailUrl;
}

public void setSiteDetailUrl(String siteDetailUrl) {
this.siteDetailUrl = siteDetailUrl;
}

}
```

I'm wondering if this is a practical way to set up the classes. Would I consider the "Video" class here to be my highest level class? Do I interact with the videos by getting a list of results from the `Video` class?  Does this make sense, or am I way off-base?

I realize this is fairly open-ended, but I'm just looking for ideas. Also looking for any reading recommendations to understand these relationships better.

Thanks!

Edit: As I look at this some more I'm wondering if I could rename `Result` to `Video` and just deal with the result objects directly as if they are videos (which they have all the attributes of). Otherwise I'm dealing with `List<Video>` all over the place and I'll have to call 'getResults()' on `Video` just to get new `List' and then I can start working with the video's attributes. I don't see a reason for the second layer.

Comment: Hey fellow duder!

What I would suggest is to create two sets of POJOs. A set for parsing the API responses, and a set of POJOs as part of your model to display. You can then create a small class to transform those API object to your model objects.

The reason for this is due to the fact that it's a 3rd party API that you don't control, it can change. So having a separation should help reduce the affects of that.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I'll look into this! Though it seems like a lot of overhead and boilerplate to create all these classes that only act as pass-through. Do you have any reference material or articles that talks about this practice?

Comment: Yeah it can be a bit more overhead but the advantage you get is controlling what data you want to extract for your domain/ui layer and also it guards you against having to significantly re-write your app should the api change as it's been isolated to just the networking layer of your app. Here's an example - https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture/issues/72